# Vue js - Error in registering components when going to the pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

I have searched a lot and any of the solutions I found were able to help me with this problem.
But basically whenever I change to a page(component) in my ASP.NET Core MVC application, it gives me this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <abc-component> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
```

I tried many thinks like registering them locally and globaly and none of them worked.

This is my Index.js:

```
import abcComponent from './abc.vue'

var element = document.getElementById('someId');

if (element) {
    Vue.component('paginate', VuejsPaginate)

    new Vue({
        el: "#someId",
        components: {
            abcComponent
        }
    });
}
```

This is my abc.vue:

```
<template>
    <section class="card double-bottom-space">

        <form class="ink-form">
            <ul class="movements-list framed half-bottom-space">
                <li class="list-head">
                    <p>Data</p>
                    <p>Movimento</p>
                    <p>Valor <small>Saldo</small></p>
                </li>
                <li v-for="item in getItems">
                    <p>{{item}}</p>
                    <p>{{item}}</p>
                    <p class="minus">{{item}} <small>{{item}}</small></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>

        <paginate v-model="currentPage"
                  :page-count="getPageCount"
                  :page-range="3"
                  :margin-pages="2"
                  :click-handler="clickCallback(currentPage)"
                  :prev-text="'＜'"
                  :next-text="'＞'"
                  :container-class="'pagination'"
                  :page-class="'page-item'">
        </paginate>

    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "abc-component",
        data: () => ({
            items: ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW"],
            parPage: 5,
            currentPage: 1
        }),
        methods: {
            clickCallback: function (currentPage) {
                this.currentPage = Number(currentPage);
            },

        },
        computed: {
            getItems: function () {
                let current = this.currentPage * this.parPage;
                let start = current - this.parPage;
                return this.items.slice(start, current);
            },
            getPageCount: function () {
                return Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.parPage);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

And this is the Razor View that will use the component:

```
<div id="someId">
    <abc-component></abc-component>
</div>
```

The bundled js is served in the Master Page/Layout Page so it doesn't need to be inserted in the Razor View.

By the way, I am checking if the Id of the div exists before building the component because in the project that I am working now, all the bundles are mixed together so I would get some errors that an HTML Element was not found. It makes no difference if I take that line of code out or not, the error of the `Unknown custom element` will still appear.

Can you guys identify something wrong with what I am doing? And if so, can you guys tell me what is wrong and why?

EDIT:
My Webpack Config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var fs = require('fs');

var appBasePath = './Scripts/'; 
var publicPath = '../bundle/'; 
var bundleExportPath = './src/bundle/'; 
var ConcatJS = './wwwroot/bundle/';

var jsEntries = {};

// We search for js files inside basePath folder and make those as entries
fs.readdirSync(appBasePath).forEach(function (name) {

    // assumption: modules are located in separate directory and each module component is imported to index.js of particular module
    var indexFile = appBasePath + name + '/index.js'
    if (fs.existsSync(indexFile)) {
        jsEntries[name] = indexFile
    }
});

const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var glob = require("glob");

var config = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader', // <style lang="scss">
                        sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax', // <style lang="sass">
                        less: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!less-loader',
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'less-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$|jsx/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { compact: false },
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },

    devtool: false,
};
       


    var JsFilesSeparatedConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
        name: "JsFilesSeparatedConfig",
        entry: jsEntries,
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, bundleExportPath),
            publicPath: publicPath,
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
                '@': path.join(__dirname, appBasePath)
            }
        },
    });

    var ConcactedJS = Object.assign({}, config, {
        name: "ConcactedJS",
        entry: glob.sync("./src/bundle/*.js"),
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, ConcatJS),
            publicPath: publicPath,
            filename: 'Main.js'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
                '@': path.join(__dirname, appBasePath)
            }
        },
    });


    module.exports = [JsFilesSeparatedConfig, ConcactedJS],
    {
        plugins: [
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /pt-pt/)
        ],
            resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
                alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
                    '@': path.join(__dirname, appBasePath)
            }
        },
    }
module.exports.watch = process.env.WATCH === "true";
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
    // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            "uglifyOptions":
            {
                compress: {
                    warnings: false
                },
                sourceMap: true
            }
        }),
    ]);
}
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev") {
    module.exports.watch = true;
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"development"'
            }
        }),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: The way you are registering your component looks fine, and your code works for me when I try it in a code sandbox. Can you add more detail about when the error happens - e.g. is it only when you change to a different page or does it happen on the first load too?

Comment: it happens on the first load too.
When I change page and when I change to the first load the error is shown. @Hannah

Comment: Are you getting any other errors at all?

Comment: Could you `console.log(abcComponent)` on the line before you mount your Vue app and see what result you get? Also, try restarting your dev server/rebuilding your project in case that fixes it.

Comment: No, I don't get any other errors before the Unknown custom element. The console.log(abcComponent) gives me an object and this object has many things

Comment: do you think it can be because I have my webpack creating 10 js files to one single js file?
When I try them alone the component error dissapears but when I try the single JS file with all the components compiled into one file gives me the error.
Do you want to see my webpack code? @Hannah

Comment: Sure, add your webpack config here I guess. Do you have any other Vue instances that might be mounting onto the same `#someId` element?

Comment: My webconfig is in the question, I edited if you want to take a look.
No, #someId is unique.
I made the test of only using the generated file of this component on the Razor view and it worked perfectly fine but when I use the file with all the components mixed it seems to give me the error that I was talking previously.
My webpack code for that matter is in the question, it might be a problem regarding the Webpack thing @Hannah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228956/discussion-between-mingo-bille-and-hannah).